# PHP cross compilation failure

Tags: php, arm, cross-compiling

I try to cross compile PHP 5.3.25 for arm-merlin on x86_64 linux.

My configure command looks like the following:

```
 export CC=/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/i686-linux/bin/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc

 ./configure --prefix=/opt/php --host=arm-merlin-linux-uclibc --target=arm-merlin-linux-uclibc --build=x86_64-linux --without-iconv --without-pear --disable-ipv6 --without-openssl --without-sqlite --without-sqlite3 --disable-pdo --without-pdo-sqlite --with-libxml-dir=/opt/libxml2/ --includedir=/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/usr/include
```

The linker fails with:

```
ext/standard/php_crypt_r.o: In function `_crypt_extended_init_r':
/projects/php/php-5.3.25/ext/standard/php_crypt_r.c:101: undefined reference to `membar_producer'
/projects/php/php-5.3.25/ext/standard/php_crypt_r.c:102: undefined reference to `atomic_add_int'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1
```

It seems that the SDK doesn't provide the correct sys/atomic.h library.
Is there a workaround for this? It would be also ok if the MD5 functionality is stripped.